# How to display the listview content in xml file in android

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have 2 xml file

1. MainActivity.xml
   2.Example.xml

I have listview in Example.xml.the code I have written in Example.java. But the data is not displaying in listview..Kindly go through my code

**Example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/profileSwitcher"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listPasscode"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"/>


</LinearLayout>
    </ViewSwitcher>
```

**Example.java**

```
public class ListViewAndroidExample extends Activity {
    ListView listView ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPasscode);

        // Define a new Adapter
        // First parameter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data

        // Array of strings...
        String[] countryArray = {"India", "Pakistan", "USA", "UK"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, countryArray);

        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_android_example);

    }

}
```

Is linking between xml and java file right ?If not suggest me

Comment: change your background of listview I think your text color of listview  and background both is white

Comment: `android.R.id.text1` is not available in the .xml xou posted. Which of those two textviews does it have to update?

Also `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`: We don't know what this is. Is this the "Example.xml" you posted?

Comment: @ManuToMatic.. Can you plz suggest me ..what it shold be ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

Add `setContentView` before initializing the  `ListView`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_android_example);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listPasscode);
```

**EDIT**

Change this..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, countryArray);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countryArray);
```